# How to make a 2-dimensional array in MySQL (using Workbench) as a key in a table?

Tags: mysql, multidimensional-array, workbench

I have a table for a movie theater. It should contain some info when is it occupied by a movie  projection. I am thinking of a 2-dimensional array - for each day in the week and each hour of the day a boolean cell indicating whether or not a projection is taking place at that theater at the given time.

I'm a beginner. Been working on Workbench only, no manually written code.

(The database is part of a larger project for website using PHP and JS.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would go for the following approach:

- a table `movie_theater` with all info about the movie theater (id,
  name, etc etc)
- a table `movie` that holds all the movies that can be shown
- a table `projection` that links a movie to a movie_theater and has a
  begin and end time_stamp

this way a projection is linked to a movie_theater and a movie.
When generating a time table for a certain period you simply select all projections from a certain movie_theater from inbetween the given timestamps